# ng-bootstarp - datepicker picks wrong date when applying OnPush ChangeDetection Strategy in component

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap, angular-changedetection

[Datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview) works fine when I don't apply `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in component. But it starts picking wrong date (sometimes) when I apply `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in component and `detach` changes in `ngAfterViewInit`.

I understand, `datepicker` modal can't apply changes to selection as I detached all changes from component. I need to have a `ng-bootstrap` callback where I can apply `detectChanges()` when user changes action in `datepicker` modal (like changing year, month, navigating month through arrow).

Here is the code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

You already have added a event which invokes when date changed, apply detect changes in that function

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="fromdp"
    [(ngModel)]="fromDate" (dateSelect)="triggerFromDateFilter($event)"
    ngbDatepicker #fromdate="ngbDatepicker">

triggerFromDateFilter(evt) {
 console.log(evt)
 this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}

triggerToDateFilter(evt) {
 console.log(evt);
 this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I just updated the code in stackblitz

Comment: @user3384985 It works see this [example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-datepicker-2u4wez)

Comment: when you click arrow navigation it does not work. Also, sometimes when you change month or year it doesn't work as well.

Comment: @user3384985 It doesn't work because `dateSelect` event is only fired when you select date from date picker(calendar), There is a `select` event which fires when user select date using keyboard or mouse [Read more here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api)

Comment: Thanks @Sameer. I'll review it and let you know how it is working.

Comment: `select` doesn't work as well. But `navigate` works except there is an error in console. Also, sometimes picker doesn't work. I updated code to stackblitz